# Creating custom fields in the yii2 for model form

Tags: yii2

I'm using active form for the generating the form.

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'name') ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'designation') ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'description')->textarea(['rows' => 6]) ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'facbook_url')?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'twitter_url')?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'pinterest_url')?>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

I want to add a custom fields in this which is not there in model.

Comment: i prefer using html helper for this task  as @Vivek Doshi answer

Comment: Solution suggested by **Bizley** is the best way to implement custom field, which will allow you to handle validation rules also.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can Yii HTML helper for the this.

```
use yii\helpers\Html;
<?= Html::textInput('first_name','',array('class'=>'form-control')) ?>
```

Refer the link for all the available methods for the class

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-html.html

Answer (score 4):

Just add these fields as public attributes in the class of `$model` and add validation rules for them.

You can find more details about this in the [Guide: Creating Forms](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-forms.html).